# Replacing part of header through functions.php

Tags: wordpress, function, genesis

I am trying to customize parts of the header.php in Wordpress Genesis framework through a code in functions.php like this:

```
if ( class_exists( 'page-template' ) ) {
    remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_header' );
    add_action( 'genesis_header', 'gd_genesis_do_header' );

    function gd_genesis_do_header() {
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

The goal is to have the modification show up on pages with a certain body class 'page-template'.

The function works without the 'if'-statement' but not with it. What could be wrong here?

Or maybe it is possible to do the action based on a page?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking for the `page-template` class on body, just check if a page template is being used on the page, like this:

```
if ( is_page_template() ) {
    remove_action( 'genesis_header', 'genesis_do_header' );
    add_action( 'genesis_header', 'gd_genesis_do_header' );

    function gd_genesis_do_header() {
        echo 'test';
    }
}
```

Here's [more information about WordPress' `is_page_template()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/). You can even use the function to check if a *specific* page template is being used. For example, `is_page_template( 'about.php' )` would return `true` if the `about.php` template was being used.

Comment: Thank you. Somehow it only works without the 'if' statement.

Answer (score 0):

To check body classes, use [get_body_class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_body_class/) NOT class_exists which checks for a PHP class used in OOP.

```
if ( in_array( 'page-template', get_body_class() ) ) {
```